# iOS MDM token invalid

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am doing iOS MSD, and I finish all the steps using SCEP with success. The device has been checked in, but when I use the device token get from the TokenUpdate MessageType for apns push, it returns

> NotificationFailureException 8 -- invalid token

I aslo write a version use pkcs12, and apns is ok.
Does anybody know why?